# Echo Array with String as Index (Without Concatenation)

Tags: php

The code below works with no problem. It prints out: hello world

```
$sample_variable = "world";
echo "hello $sample_variable";
```

Now, I am trying to implement the same logic but this time with an array whos indexes are strings. The following code below is what I have come up with. It causes an error and fails to print out the expected output. (expected output: The product Whey is for sale for 3000)

```
$product = array(
"product_name" => "Whey", 
"product_price" => 3000
);

echo "The product $product['product_name'] is for sale for $product['product_price']";
```

My question: How can I echo an array  with string as an index **without** the use of PHP concatenation operator ('.') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use as below

```
<?php

$product = array(
"product_name" => "Whey", 
"product_price" => 3000
);

echo "The product $product[product_name] is for sale for $product[product_price]";
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this **without the concatenation operator**:

```
$product=array(
                "product_name"=>"whey",
                "product_price"=>3000
```

using double quote you can do :

```
echo "The product $product[product_name] is for sale for $product[product_price]";
echo "The product ${product["product_name"]} is for sale for ${product["product_price"]}";
```

with preformatted string:

```
printf("The product %s is for sale for %s ",$product['product_name'],$product['product_price']);
echo sprintf("The product %s is for sale for %s ",$product['product_name'],$product['product_price']);
```

when your array contains lot of data just write the string and unpack the array with ...

```
printf("The product %s is for sale for %s ",...array_values($product));//php >=5.6
echo sprintf("The product %s is for sale for %s ",...array_values($product));//php >=5.6
```

the output is:

```
The product whey is for sale for 3000
```